# how to retrieve the @rid value from a query select from User where name = 'Nicole' using pyorient

Tags: orientdb, orientdb2.2, pyorient

I have not figure it out yet, how to retrieve the `@rid` value from the record metadata using python 3.5 with pyorient client.command to run such SQL query.

Let's said that I have created a User class using the following query in the `client.command(query)` of pyorient. For simplicity only the queries calls will be shown here:

```
CREATE User EXTENDS V
CREATE PROPERTY User.name IF NOT EXISTS STRING (MANDATORY TRUE, NOTNULL TRUE)
CREATE INDEX User.name ON User (name) UNIQUE
```

Let's create a dictionary to hold the pointers of recent created vertex

```
rec = {}
```

Now we add some vertex:

```
rec['Cleo'] = CREATE VERTEX User CLUSTER User CONTENT {'name': 'Cleopatra'}
rec['Alex'] = CREATE VERTEX User CLUSTER User CONTENT {'name': 'Alex'}
```

Let's see the value of `rec['Alex']`:

```
rec['Alex']
[<pyorient.otypes.OrientRecord at 0x7fc39cd69c50>]
```

Let's said that, we want to know the @rid for Alex, so we can later on use it to create Edges among other classes.

If I run a quety using orientdb studio I can see the @rid:

[image]

but, if I run the same query using client.command I get the a list with the two record pointers. So it is the same as having the result from `rec['Alex']`

so, if I do `rec['Alex'][0].oRecordData` to get the record data, I only get back:

```
{'name': 'Alex'}
```

(1) How can I store the `rid` in a variable when I create a new vertex?

(2) How can I retrieve the rid for a record when you know, let's said the property `name` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the python driver you need to do : ret._rid to access the rid